# Wordpress Site is not connecting to stylesheets

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am designing a wordpress site, it is on production level, I am running the Divi Theme. Recently this site wont connect to the stylesheets provided. It will connect off and on, so i will have an incognito tab open with the site, when i hard refresh, 6 of the stylesheets wont connect in the network tab of inspect. If i wait anywhere from 5 mins to an hour and refresh again it might work and it might not. It also sometimes works on chrome and not safari at the same time to refresh. We have also purged all the cache on page and CDN level.

This only seems to be the problem on the Home page, because none of the other pages have those stylesheets.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are having the same issue, we have found the answer.

We found the solution, when you purge cache in wordpress at a page level, make sure you are not only purging the objects, but purging the utilities and the full page.